# Find a matrix from its eigenvalues and corresponding vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus, matrix-equations, diagonalization

> Suppose $A$ is a $3 \times 3$ matrix with eigenvalues $\lambda_1=-1$ $\lambda_2=0$ and $\lambda_3=1$ and with the corresponding eigenvectors $\vec{v_1}=<1,0,2>$  $\vec{v_2}=<-1,1,0>$ and $\vec{v_3}=<0,0,1>$
>
> Find matrix the $A$

So I made $P=$
$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\
2 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$
and got $P^{-1} =$
$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\
-2 & -2 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

I am unsure where to go from here though? I feel as though maybe there is missing information in the question?

Comment: Hinr. If you use the eigenvectors as a basis the matrix will have the eigenvalues on the diagonal. By this time in your linear algebra studies you should have learned how changing the basis affects the matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The searched matrix is $M=PDP^{-1}$ where $D$ is the diagonal matrix that has as diagonal elements the eigenvalues, in the same order as the eigenvectors in $P$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix)).

$$
M=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&-1&0\\
0&1&0\\
2&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
-1&0&0\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&0\\
0&1&1\\
-2&-2&1
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
-1&-1&0\\
0&0&0\\
-4&-4&1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*:

$$\begin{pmatrix}a&b&c\\d&e&f\\g&h&i\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-1\\0\\-2\end{pmatrix}$$

and the same with other eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Answer (score 0):

$A=P \Lambda P^{-1}$, where $\Lambda=diag(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_3)$